# Platform Project Financing

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

I am new to this community and I have been studying ethereum for 1 month now. I have signed up @ ethethereum.org with an abstract concept (potential prototype). I would like people to sign up on my platform to earn ether. The problem is, I don't have any either. Nor am I a miner (or interested in doing do). What other way's are there to finance a project? I do know they have the crowd funding route. Are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting approach to fund a community project is outlined [here](https://forum.bitsquare.io/t/bitsquare-as-decentralized-autonomous-organization/38).

This does however come with the limitation that funding will start only once a minimum viable product exists and is being used.
For upfront funding you either need a crowdfunding / ICO or other traditional methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "only once a minimum viable product exists and is being used"  Who says you need a product to earn either.